What is the significance of this equation for safely estimating a lower-bound value?
I have encountered a formula for safely estimating a lower-bound value of some property.
$$k = N \cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$X = X_m \cdot \left(1 - k \cdot \mathrm{CoV} \right)$$
where $N$ is the number of standard deviations to a desired fractile, say $0.05$ (i.e. the z-score), $n$ is the number of sample points used for estimating, $X_m$ is the mean value, and $\mathrm{CoV}$ is the coefficient of variation.
Now, notice that in the first equation, if there was only $1/n$ under the square root, than the whole expression would give the $0.05$ fractile of a distribution defined by the mean and the standard error – which would be a safe estimate of the mean. However, with the addition of${}+ 1,$ it is supposed to give a safe estimate of a lower-bound value, but I cannot figure out what the result actually represents.
I understand that for $n \to \infty.$ the result is the $0.05$ fractile of the whole sample or population distribution, and that for lower number of observations the z-score increases – but why does it increase as much as it does, what is this rule? That might be the real question.

Could you please explain what you mean by "safe"? // The formula is recognizable as the algebraic equivalent of subtracting $k$ SDs from the mean.  But if we assume "$X_m$" is a sample mean and "$CoV$" is a sample CV, then this equation is incorrect: it works only in the limit of extremely large $n$ and the proper value of $k$ to use depends on assumptions about the data distribution. It can work only under rather severe restrictions, suggesting we need to know more about the application if we're to provide accurate advice.

"Safe" is arbitrarily defined here. For example, if I want to get estimate an average value but be on the safe side, I would subtract N standard errors from the mean (N usually corresponds to the 0.05 fractile). In the case of the above expressions, k is much larger than both the standard error and the sample SD. The properties that are estimated with these expression are assumed normally distributed. // Could you elaborate on the restrictions, assumptions and errors of the expressions?
